# Validator not working in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

The validator in my zend  framework 2 are not working. Even as you can see required=>true works and shows me error if I pass an empty string. But the min and max length validations are not working and $form->isValid() just return true. Any help will be appreciated. 
I'm following this tutorial on Zend website. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

```
<?php

namespace AdminAuthentication\Model;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;

class Login implements InputFilterAwareInterface{
    public $username;
    public $password;

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray($data){
        $this->username = isset($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : null;
        $this->password = isset($data['password']) ? $data['password'] : null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter){
        throw new \Exception("Not Used!");
    }

    public function getInputFilter(){

        if( ! $this->inputFilter ){

            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim' ),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringLength',
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 5,
                        'max' => 35

                    )

                )
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim' ),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringLength',
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 5

                    )

                )
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;

        }
        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed something in the [documentation tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html). Your code is wrong.

You have :

```
'validators' => array(
                array('name' => 'StringLength',
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 5,
                    'max' => 35

                )

            )
```

You should have this :

```
'validators' => array (
                    array (
                            'name' => 'StringLength',
                            'options' => array (//<-----options array here
                                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                    'min' => 1,
                                    'max' => 100 
                            ) 
                    ) 
            )
```

The `min`, `max` and `encoding` should be in the `options` array.

Answer (score 2):

Well, above code was in documentation and not working. I don't know the reason but I've found the solution. For validator, replace

```
'validators' => array(
                array('name' => 'StringLength',
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min' => 5

                )

            )
```

with

```
'validators' => array(
                new StringLength(
                    array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min' => 5
                    )
                ),

            ),
```

Here is the complete code.

```
namespace AdminAuthentication\Model;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\Validator\StringLength;

class Login implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    public $username;
    public $password;

    protected $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->username = isset($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : null;
        $this->password = isset($data['password']) ? $data['password'] : null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not Used!");
    }

    public function getInputFilter()
    {

        if (!$this->inputFilter) {

            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    new StringLength(
                        array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 5,
                            'max' => 35

                        )
                    ),

                ),
            )));

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'password',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    new StringLength(
                        array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 5
                        )
                    ),

                ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;

        }
        return $this->inputFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: for new StringLength